# How to use Jsoup in an Android app to show certain text from a website?

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

I want to learn jsoup and went through some tutorials and the documentation, but they are outdated and the functions used son't work anymore. I understood how we get a website into a document by

> Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect("https://crackwatch.com/").get();

But what after it?

For example I want to get the text Cracked or Uncracked from this page: https://crackwatch.com/game/detroit-become-human

How do i do that? Please give the code along with what each line does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using JSOUP to get "Current Version" from PlayStore to ForceUpdate the app, you can take help from my code :

```
 private class ForceUpdateAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        private Context context;
        private String currentVersion;
        private AppStartupThreadResponse response;

        public ForceUpdateAsync(Context context, String currentVersion, AppStartupThreadResponse response) {
            this.context = context;
            this.currentVersion = currentVersion;
            this.response = response;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String newVersion = null;
            try {
                //HTML Parsing of the data coming from the url
                Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vassar.unifiedapp.dmaedu&hl=en_IN")
                        .timeout(30000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"))
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .get();
                if (document != null) {

                    Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
                    for (Element ele : element) {
                        if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                            Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                            for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                                newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return newVersion;
        }
```